# Getting values from Component to view in queryParams inside anchor

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am applying global navigation on one of my component page.

MyComponent

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  sampleId: number;
  ngOnInit() {
    try {
      this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.sampleId = params['sampleId'];
        this.router.navigate(["/samples"], { queryParams: { id: this.sampleId} });
      })
     }
   }
}
```

app-rounting.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'samples', component: MyComponentViewComponent }]
```

View

```
<li class="style-cls" [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
  <a [routerLink]="['/samples']" [queryParams]="{id: this.sampleId }">Samples</a>
</li>
```

I am getting an error to display the navigation using anchor tag. In queryparams, how can I get the value of id which is assigned in component so that I can navigate.

Comment: It's not very clear, what you want to achieve here. Is it, you want to route to '/samples' from a different view! Please elaborate more, I can give you a stackblitz site to play more

Comment: I am setting sampleId parameter in this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.sampleId = params['sampleId'];
      }), but I want this sampleId on a global level outside this subscribe method. After I get that at global level, I want to access this sampleId in same view in anchor tag's query param method